How to have a single view be shared across multiple tabs in a TabView in SwiftUI
I have a TabView that shows 2 tabs:
struct TestInitial: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("Content 1")
                .tabItem { Text("Tab 1") }
            
            Text("Content 2")
                .tabItem { Text("Tab 2") }
        }
    }
}

I wanted to add something similar to a paywall to access content, which I did like so:
struct Test: View {
    @State private var isAuthorised = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Group {
                if isAuthorised {
                    Text("Content 1")
                } else {
                    BlockView()
                }
            }
            .tabItem { Text("Tab 1") }
            
            Group {
                if isAuthorised {
                    Text("Content 2")
                } else {
                    BlockView()
                }
            }
            .tabItem { Text("Tab 2") }
        }
    }
}

Using Group and a Conditional like this makes it unnecessarily hard to read in my opinion. I wonder, is there a simple way to share the same view between each tab? In addition to readability, in contexts where BlockView had some state, it would be beneficial for SwiftUI to use the same memory for each tab.
Is there any way to tell SwiftUI that each tab is using the same view?

You can't share a view. SwiftUI view structs are very lightweight so memory use isn't an issue.  I would put isAuthorised into an observable in the environment and then have the view in each tab decide what to show based on that value.

You might also want to use the redacted view modifier.

Create your own ViewModifierbit wouldn’t be the same view but you can clean up the code. You can share state with SceneStorage or AppStorage.

You could change the Groups to 2 custom subviews
